# Adding a second toolbar to JQGrid using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Is there any way to add a second toolbar to existing JQGrid from JQueryUI.

Comment: What kind of toolbar you mean? Is it the toolbar above the grid additionally with the toober (navigator bar) at the bottom of the ggrid? Which information you would like to place on the toolber: your custom buttons or some standard buttons of jqGrid?

Comment: I wanted to add some custom buttons to my second toolbar, while keeping the Navigational bar untouched.

Comment: Look at [the picture](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/lib/exe/detail.php?id=wiki%3Ahow_it_works&media=wiki:allgridelementsnewfilters1.png). Where you want have the second toolber?

Comment: Exactly below the Grid(on the right bottom corner of the grid below Navigational Bar).

Comment: Is it not easier to describe more detailed what you want and not spent the time in writing many comments? Is the "bottom toolbar" what you mean or not? I asked you before: "Which information you would like to place on the toolber: your custom buttons or some standard buttons of jqGrid?". Which jQuery UI elements you want to place inside? Could you post an example?

Comment: In that toolbar, we wanted to add few icons. Each icons will have some functionality. For example, preferences icon, using which i want to control the display of columns of the grid. Each user may wanted to set different order or the columns and even different columns, so this icon will give that facility to the user. Like this we have several other functions. The second toolbar supposed to have this kind of icons for each of these functions. That's design Ufx team gave it to us. It's not the default buttons we wanted.We wanted to place the this new toolbar at the bottom of the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toolbar: [true, "bottom"]` option of jqGrid to add additional toolbar at the bottom of grid. The id of the grid will be constructed from `'t_'` prefix and the grid id. You can add any information to the grid manually. For example the following code add simple [jQuery UI Button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/):

```
$('<div><span id="myToolbar" style="float: right;"></span></div>').appendTo("#t_" + $grid[0].id);
$('<button>', {title: 'Click me!'}).css({
    float: "right",
    height: "21px",
    width: "20px"
}).appendTo("#myToolbar").button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-gear"
            },
            text: false
        }).click(function (e) {
            alert('My button was clicked');
        });
```

you can see the results on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SecondToolbar.htm):

[image]
(I placed the cursor over the button to show the tooltip "Click me!")

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I have done using some other way. But this code is more than efficient than my code.