# Add column-specific buttons to jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm trying to add column-specific buttons to jqGrid, where the filter toolbar would be. 

The closest solution I could find is [adding button adjacent to filter toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811045/adding-button-adjacent-to-filter-toolbar), except that I want the button above/below the toolbar, and I will have one for each column. 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toolbar: [true, "top"]` then jqGrid crates additional toolbar integrated in the jqGrid header. You can place and buttons on the toolbar and archive your goals.

Comment: do you have any examples in jqGrid documentation in how that might work?

Comment: @zzxx53: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9310762/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8445240/315935) for example.